# How to constraint only one checkbox selected when there is two, typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, button, constraints

The buttons :

```
<nb-checkbox status="success" 
     OUTDOOR
</nb-checkbox>
<nb-checkbox status="success">
     INDOOR
</nb-checkbox>
```

If i select the OUTDOOR checkbox while the INDOOR button is selected, INDOOR has to be unselected and the OUTDOOR selected.Same thing for the opposite.

Comment: To be clear, you are using Nebular with Angular 2+ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when options are mutually exclusive, the common paradigm is to use a radio button group. Since you are using Nebular, see:
 https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/radio/overview#nbradiocomponent

However, if you really want to use checkboxes, consider this `[checked]` and `(change)` toggle.

In your typescript component.

```js
public status: "indoor" | "outdoor";
```

In your template

```html
<nb-checkbox 
    [checked]="status == outdoor"
    (change)="status = 'outdoor'">
     OUTDOOR
</nb-checkbox>
<nb-checkbox 
    [checked]="status == indoor"
    (change)="status = 'indoor'">
     INDOOR
</nb-checkbox>
```

Comment: how to you bind radio with variables of the component ?

Comment: with true and false